# Match string to multiple globs in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to simplify my Bash 4 script. I'm reading lines from a file and I want to exclude lines matching certain substrings:

```
while read p; do
    if [[ $p != *-ext ]]; then
        if [[ $p != *-backend ]]; then
                if [[ $p != *-vip ]]; then
                    echo $p
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
done < $hostsfile
```

So if the line does NOT end with -ext or -backend or -vip then print it. What's an easier way (one-liner that doesn't chain &&'s) to accomplish this?

Comment: These aren't regexes at all, they're glob-style pattern matches. (Well, in the *formal* sense, glob-style pattern matches are with extglob enabled regex-equivalent, but it's not POSIX BRE or ERE syntax, or any superset thereof).

Comment: As another aside, you don't need to quote inside `[[ ]]` (well, not in any scenarios that matter for the code in this question), but you *should* quote the expansion in `echo "$p"`; likewise for the redirection, `< "$hostfile"`. Without the quotes, `echo $p` will expand globs -- so if given `p='* -ext`, `echo $p` would print a list of all files in the current directory. Redirections, on the other hand, can fail with an error if they expand to anything other than a single word when string-split and glob-expanded when not quoted.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I fixed the title. I knew about the quotes previously but thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an extended pattern. This requires the `extglob` option be enabled, but that is (temporarily) enabled by default for the RHS of the `!=` operator inside `[[` in `bash` 4.2 or later.

```
shopt -s extglob  # if necessary
if [[ $p != *-@(backend|vip|ext) ]]; then
```

---

An equivalent using regular expressions would be

```
if ! [[ $p =~ (backend|vip|ext)$ ]]; then
```

No additional options need to be set, but a regular expression isn't implicitly anchored, so you *don't* need to match the beginning of the string like `*-` does in the pattern, but you *do* need to explicitly match the end of the string with `$`. Also, there is no doesn't-match regular-expression operator (like `!~` in Perl), so you need to use `=~` and negate the exit status of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a POSIX-compliant option (portable to `/bin/sh`) to the otherwise very good answer already present:

```
case $p in *-backend|*-vip|*-ext) : ;; *) echo "$p" ;; esac
```

Split out onto multiple lines, that would look like:

```
case $p in
  *-backend|*-vip|*-ext)
    :
    ;;
  *)
    echo "$p"
    ;;
esac
```

...that is to say, we're running the `:` command (shorthand for `true`) if any of the patterns is matched, and our `echo` otherwise.